# Understanding PHP files and AJAX calls

Tags: php, ajax

I'm slowly learning PHP ;-) I'm having difficulties understanding how separate PHP-files work together.

I make AJAX calls to different php files that all need to be connected to the backend (Parse). Such as:

```
sign_up.php
login.php
verify_email.php
get_something_out_of_the_database.php
```

What is the standard way to stay logged in over the different php files? (or what is the google search term for it..?)

*Update*:
Thanks for all your answers about 'sessions'. I doesn't work very well yet, so i made a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861430/php-sessions-and-parse).

Thanks!

Remzo

Comment: You must create a file and initialize the session in it, as `session_start()` and include this file, anywhere you need to authenticate a user or provide some thing base on sessions

Comment: Use [SESSIONS](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: `stay logged in over the different php files` how about bootstraping your application. Means: every call is redirected to `index.php` and there you can check for loggin and so on. Thats how frameworks do it.  OldSchool but also works: use autoprepend function from php http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file and do the checks there.(less code work for you)

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP sessions. These are a way to store information on visitor browser between multiple pages...

To start a session, you first need to add `session_start();` in every PHP file you intend to use it. Usually it's added in a header.php

Then, you can use sessions already.

To store a result:

```
$_SESSION['some_data'] = $var;
```

To retrieve a result in another page, for example:

```
echo $_SESSION['some_data']; // will echo $var
```

More info can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for example by storing the login-data in a session-variable and checking it at the start of every new page.

Example:
You check if login-data is valid. Then

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["login"] = $loginname;
```

At the start of another page:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]) || $_SESSION["login"] != "check_somehow")
{
  header("Location: logout.php");
  exit;
}
```

For logging out you can use

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Thanks!! If i understand it correctly, this solutions transfers user data in a variable to another php file. But suppose this other php file needs to get something out of the database. Does it then have to log itself in again? And is it then logged in twice...?

Comment: This starts a session which is available across all the php files, now you can validate this session by checking diffrerent values set( as per your requirements). You don't need to logging again in the same session

Comment: I've tried the session_start for a few hours now. But ... it doesn't work for me in combination with calling PARSE. AAAAAAAHHHHHH. If i remove session_start from my php file, i can retrieve info from the Parse database. I don't have the Session variables then. If i add session_start() i can access the Session variables, but i cannot connect to Parse anymore. HELP ! (-;  (i will change my question)

Answer (score 0):

On the start of your user logged in, you can do something like

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['USER'] = <some user info>;
```

In your other pages you can see if

```
if(isset($_SESSION['USER'])){
  // do something
```

}

at last on logout

```
session_destroy();
```

will kill the session

Comment: Thanks!! If i understand it correctly, this solutions transfers user data in a variable to another php file. But suppose this other php file needs to get something out of the database. Does it then have to log itself in again? And is it then logged in twice...?